# Same process IDs of all IE windows

Tags: c#, watin

When I manually launch Internet Explorer windows, each one of them gets a different PID.

However, suppose I have manually opened one browser window and it gets PID 12345 and then run WaitiN which opens some browser windows, the PIDs of all WaiiN windows becomes 12345. How can I change the behaviour so that WatiN works like it works manually.

I need the PIDs so that I can close the broswer windows opened by WatiN in my cleanup code and make sure I close the PIDs of browser windows opened only by WatiN.

**EDIT:**
Code I am using is:

```
//Where I am using WatiN 1
IE ReportWindow = IE.AttachToNoWait<IE>(Find.ByTitle("New Activity Recap"), 120);
ReportWindowPID = ReportWindow.ProcessID;

//Where I am using WatiN 2
IE ReportWindow = IE.AttachToNoWait<IE>(Find.ByTitle("New Activity Recap"), 120);
ReportWindowPID = ReportWindow.ProcessID;

//Cleanup code
            foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore"))
            {
                if (p.Id == ApplicationWindowPID || p.Id == ReportWindowPID)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        p.Kill();
                        p.WaitForExit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

The above code is closing the 2 windows opened by WatiN as well as other windows.

**PS:** ANy code which kills the browser windows by a URL can also do because the base URL is going to be the same in the 2 WatiN windows.

Comment: Do you have any current code where you are getting Processes `Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses();`

Comment: you need to do something like 
`Process prc =GetAProcess(p.ProcessName);` then `prc.Kill();`